# NyroModal, access data from parent page

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I am using a nyroModal with an Iframe via target=_blank. In the parent page I have a set of checkboxes and base on what is checked i want to add some extra data to the modal window.

Is there i way that I can access those checkboxes from the modal?

I have also tried to modify the link to the page and send them info from checkboxes as parameters using

```
    $(mapModalSelector).nyroModal();
    $(mapModalSelector).click('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = 'base/view/'+jsonData;
        $.nmManual(link);

        return false;
   });
```

but in this way it loops somehow and i get extra close buttons and the page is not rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it something like this , For example reading text box present on parent then

```
 parent.document.getElementById('myTxtBoxId').value
```